ASP.Net. Как встроить WebGL игру в свой сайт?
Разрабатываю свой сайт с размещением игр. У меня есть WebGL-билд, у которого есть непосредственно файл html c игрой, вопрос как ее встроить в свой сайт. Я использую ASP.Net.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Getting_started_with_WebGL
